# How to get text between two div tags with some class attribute with HTMLagility

Tags: c#, html, selector, html-agility-pack, dom

I want to get some text from two html div from HTML file.
After some searches i decided to use HTMLAgility Pack for doing this.
I wrote this code :

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(result);
    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*div[@class='item']"); 
    string value = node.InnerText;
```

'result' is my content of the File.
But i get this exception : 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set'

And this is some of mt file's content :

```
<div class="Clear" style="height:15px;"></div>
<div class='Container Select' id="Container_1">
<div class='Item'><div class='Part Lable'>موضوع : </div><div class='Part ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try either

`"//*/div[@class='item']"`

or simply

`"//div[@class='item']"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.when i use some string and putting my value for test,all of these selectors worked,but when i read from file and use the selector some exceptions thrown ...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using XPath
for example if I wanated to find a if a node is selected in my example I would do the following

```
string xpath = null;
XmlNode configNode = configDom.DocumentElement;
// collect selected nodes in node list
XmlNodeList nodeList =
configNode.SelectNodes(@"//*[@status='checked']");
```

in your case you would do the following

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(result);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*/div[@class='item']"); 
string value = node.InnerText;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.what is configDom.DocumentElement type?i think you type in wrong